# Wildcards for lcov.info path in the SonarQube scanners?

Tags: sonarqube, lcov, sonarjs

I can't seem to use wildcards to specify a path to my `lcov.info` file in the SonarQube MSBuild Scanner. e.g.:

```
/d:sonar.javascript.lcov.reportPath="..\..\build\coverage\lcov\*\lcov.info"
```

but if I specify the full path, it works:

```
/d:sonar.javascript.lcov.reportPath="..\..\build\coverage\lcov\Chrome 57.0.2987 (Windows 10 0.0.0)\lcov.info"
```

This is going to vary depending on what browser is on the build agent!

Any idea how I can get around this?

Answer (score 2):

Currently there is no way to do that. I've created [this issue](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-javascript/issues/578) to address the problem.